# input object for the component is always null in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am learning Angular.

I am trying to call my parent component from child component, but when I tried to call the child component, I got the error "undefined" for the child component
so, after looking at few posts on Stack Overflow, I changed my call of the child component from `@viewChild` to `@ViewChildren`. Now my child component is not throwing an error of undefined, but the variable that I have defined in child component is undefined and calling that same variable in my parent component is undefined. Below is my call from parent component to child component:

```
@ViewChildren('projectadd') projectcomponent: ProjectAddComponent;
```

After making the call, I am doing:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('on after view init', this.projectcomponent);

}
```

and after the above code I am calling a method that initializes a value to my variables. I am always getting undefined for the variable `objProjectDetails`. I have defined `objProjectDetails` in my child component like this:

```
@Input() objProjectDetails: AllItProject = new AllItProject();
```

and below is the call to the variable from my parent component:

```
this.projectcomponent.objProjectDetails.name = '';
```

My partial code for parent component:

```
export class AngularCRUDComponent implements OnInit {
projectlist: AllItProject[];
dataavailbale: boolean = false;
tempproject: AllItProject;
constructor(private dataservce: ProjectDataService, private route: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.LoadProjectData();
    console.log('on init', this.projectcomponent);

  }
LoadProjectData() {  //code here for loading the project data}

 @ViewChildren('projectadd') projectcomponent: ProjectAddComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('on after view init', this.projectcomponent);

}

loadAddnew() {

    this.projectcomponent.*objProjectDetails*.name = '';  // getting undefined for objprojectDetails right here
    this.projectcomponent.objProjectDetails.description = '';
    this.projectcomponent.objProjectDetails.type = '';}
```

This is the code for my child component:

```
export class ProjectAddComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()  cleardata: boolean = false;
  @Output() nameEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  objtempproject: AllItProject;
  @Input() objProjectDetails: AllItProject = new AllItProject();
  @ViewChild('closeBtn', {read: true, static: false}) cb: ElementRef;
  projectlist: AllItProject[];

constructor(private dataservice: ProjectDataService, private route: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService) {
    // code here
 }
```

`AllItProject` is defined in modal folder like so:

```
export class AllItProject {

  name: string;
  description: string;
  type: string; }
```

I am not sure why am I getting undefined for `objProjectDetails` in my parent component.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: Try  @ViewChild(ProjectAddComponent) projectcomponent: ProjectAddComponent;

Comment: Hi Maihan,  it is eventemitter that I was missing. you can post your solution as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a sulution here =)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-58456211

If you want to send data to your child component use the input through the html tag

parent.component.html

```
<child-component [objProjectDetails]="parentObjectWithProjectDetailsData"></child-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```
let parentObjectWithProjectDetailsData = {name: 'Desired Name', description: 'Your Description', type: 'Your Type'}
```

If you update parentObjectWithProjectDetailsData with some fetched data it will automatically de reflected on your child component

Comment: i could not open the link that you mentioned in your message

Answer (score 1):

You can use either @Inject() or @Injectable().
@Inject() is a manual mechanism for letting Angular know that a parameter must be injected.

```
constructor(@Inject(ProjectAddComponent) private ProjectAddComponent) { 
  console.log(this.ProjectAddComponent.objProjectDetails);
}
```

And @Injectable() lets Angular know that a class can be used with the dependency injector.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectAddComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

More details [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)
and [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable)